# Can't resolve 'fs' during require svelte/register

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Hello I am experimenting with svelte/register: https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_register

But when I add `require('svelte/register');` into my file so I get error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/svelte/register.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/martin/Projects/LearnEnglishWordsV3/node_modules/svelte'
 @ ./node_modules/svelte/register.js 1:9-22
 @ ./src/views/WordListView.svelte
 @ ./src/components/App.svelte
 @ ./src/js/app.js

Build failed with errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Do you anybody know what I have to do for fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require('svelte/register')` can only be used in node.js to compile the imported svelte files. It seems that you're calling it in the browser, which it then complains about `fs` (a node.js module).

If your goal is to compile svelte files in the browser, use [svelte.compile](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_compile), which is also what `svelte/register` uses under the hood. But do note that it brings a larger bundle size.

Otherwise, you can just safely remove `require('svelte/register')`.